# How to get self-differences in sqlite table

Tags: sqlite, logic

does anyone know if there is a way to get this result in SQLite.

Given table with single column x like this:

```
x |
--
1
4
5
2
```

I need to add column dx, which is simply a difference x_i - x_{i-1} (except for the first one) like this:

```
x | dx |
--  --
1 | 0
4 | 3
5 | 1
2 | -3
```

Thanks a lot!

Update: given there is id column:

```
id | x |
--  --
1  | 1
2  | 4
3  | 5
4  | 2
```

Is it possible to obtain:

```
id | x | dx |
--   --  --
1  | 1 | 0
2  | 4 | 3
3  | 5 | 1
4  | 2 | -3
```

Comment: This question arose when I was processing experimental data. Now, I would most likely use python pandas dataframe module instead of the sqlite database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables have no implicit order associated with them. You must supply an `ORDER BY` clause to impose an order on the results.

What column would you order by to define the predecessor row for the subtraction? (Hint: there is none.)

With the addition of an `id` column per the revised question

```
sqlite> select id, x, (select t1.x - t2.x from t as t2 where id = t1.id - 1) from t as t1;
1|1|
2|4|3
3|5|1
4|2|-3
```

Or

```
sqlite> select id, x, coalesce((select t1.x - t2.x from t as t2 where id = t1.id - 1),0) from t as t1;
1|1|0
2|4|3
3|5|1
4|2|-3
```

Comment: Probably, this should work. However, I have more than 40,000,000 records in my table. What makes things a little bit more tricky is the fact that id is actually a float number and the difference t1.id - t2.id may vary. One of possible solutions may be to introduce ids column. Thanks for the basic idea, it should help.